# Minor version returns only single digit in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my console application my requirement was

```
I/P:
Version : 10.01
```

Expected O/P:

```
Major Version : 10
Minor Version : 01
```

but returns as Minor Version :1

```
Console.Write("Enter the version : ");
var readVersion = Console.ReadLine();
Version version = new Version(readVersion);
Console.WriteLine("Major Version : " + version.Major);
Console.WriteLine("Minor Version : " + version.Minor);
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? The [version parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.minor(v=vs.110).aspx) are *integers*. If you want to display them using a certain format, change your `WriteLine` to include a format string

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Minor Version : {0:D2}", version.Minor);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this,

```
Console.WriteLine("Minor Version : " + version.Minor.ToString("D2"));
```

And also,

```
Console.WriteLine("Minor Version : {0:D2}", version.Minor);
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Or `Console.WriteLine("Minor Version : {0:D2}", version.Minor); ` and avoid generating a temporary string

Comment: Thanks but Instead of using this string manipulations , i can able to get the exact value in some other machines so i need to some clarifications on how it is works properly in other machine , why it's not working in my machine?

Comment: Is there any changes required for this issue in system level instead of using code level ? i mean any changes in current culture settings ?

Comment: Culture settings can be the problem,otherwise taking integer will always ignore 0 beginning of the integer. @krishbala